# requets are redirected to login.aspx?ReturnUrl=

Tags: servicestack, xsp

I have implemented a webservice using servicestack using Visual Studio. Running the service from the vs debugger works just fine. I have just tried to deploy it to a debian machine using XSP4. The service makes use of logging, from what I can tell the service is up and running. A log file is created when I start the service, but any request I make does not work. For instance, I make the following request using a browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1/Activity/5b1e5316-8ea5-4ba5-aaee-7f40151b80d3/Unit
```

But the browser is being redirected to:

```
http://127.0.0.1/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fActivity%2f5b1e5316-8ea5-4ba5-aaee-7f40151b80d3%2fUnit
```

I have implemented my own authentication using a global requestfilter that I add in the Configure method. I am very confused why the request is redirected to login.aspx. Also, in the log file is see the following:

Error 2013-01-10 00:07:53.2631 NotFoundHttpHandler 192.168.23.2 Request not found: /login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fActivity%2f5b1e5316-8ea5-4ba5-aaee-7f40151b80d3%2fUnit

Does anybody have any idea what may cause this behaviour? Here is the code that adds the global filter:

```
this.RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var userCreds = httpReq.GetBasicAuthUserAndPassword();

                if (userCreds == null)
                {
                    httpResp.ReturnAuthRequired();
                    return;
                }

                var userName = userCreds.Value.Key;
                var userPass = userCreds.Value.Value;

                if (!TryResolve<IAuthenticationProvider>().AuthenticateUser(userName, userPass))
                {
                    httpResp.ReturnAuthRequired();
                }

                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {   
                log.Error(ex);
                throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This looks like an ASP.NET redirection issue in your Web.Config. ServiceStack doesn't redirect to any `login.aspx` page.

Comment: I have the same issue but with MVC. the authentication is set to None in web.config as well.

Comment: I had same problem with MVC after adding the <authentication mode="None" />.  I added the following to web.config (system.webServer/modules) <add name="FormsAuthenticationDisposition" type="ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule, ServiceStack.ServiceInterface" />

Comment: @sam if you were to post your comment as an answer, I would upvote it ;)

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it out. I added

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

to the Web.config like so:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- mode=[Windows|Forms|Passport|None] -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```

The documentation can be found here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I used the snippet below to solve my woes with .NET Forms auth overriding the 401 I'm trying to return via ServiceStack.NET. On every request, at the beginning, if it's AJAX, immediately suppress the behavior. This flag was created by MS for just this purpose. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.suppressformsauthenticationredirect.aspx

Note that many other solutions that show up when searching tell you disable .NET auth, which is simply not feasible in the majority of cases. This code works with no other modifications.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    HttpRequestBase request = new HttpRequestWrapper(Context.Request);
    if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        Context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
    }
}
```